# How to solve: $x^4+x^2=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I solved $x^4+x^2+1=0$. But, the above one is hard. The equation is too hard for me to understand. Can anyone solve it? Please help.

Comment: You know how to solve quadratic equations??

Comment: @Sohaib, is it $\;1\;$ or $\;-1\;$ ? . Also, read http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Over what field do you want to solve this?

Comment: It's a simple quadratic equation for $x^2$. Then it's not far from $x^2$ to $x$.

Comment: @Ross: note the $-1$ on the right side the equation in the post.

Comment: @RossMillikan It is not the same. The one in the question has a positive $1$ on the right hand side of the equation. The other one a $-1$. If this is on $\mathbb{R}$, obviously the second one is easy...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$x^4+x^2=1$$

put $x^2=t$
And you'll have a quadratic in $t$
$$t^2+t-1=0$$ using quadratic formula we get
$$t=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Now you can find $x$ using $x^2=t$ we get

> $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}},\pm i\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}}$$ where  $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: Forget about the downvoters, from time to time you get one that doesn't make sense(or you wasn't rigorous enough)..I for one gave an up vote. Also, it could be a mistake (I know I have done that) and I believe you can't change the vote back unless you edit the question.